# Culture is "laid back" or "forward looking"

Tags: meaning

I recently read [this](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Athens_vs_Sparta) comparison on Athens and Sparta, and the culture part caught my eye.

[image]

I googled for the meaning, but came up with nothing.

What does it mean to have a forward looking culture vs one that is laid back? Does it mean that you are looking to improve vs staying where you are, respectively? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think part of your difficulty may be that the contention of the original article is preposterous.  Of all the descriptions of ancient Spartan culture I have encountered, I can't recall any one that ever said anything even vaguely along the lines of "laid back".  Militaristic, yes.  Strict, yes. Ruthless, yes.  Proud, yes.  Hardcore, yes. Laid back.... not so much.

Answer (score 2):

"Looking to improve vs staying where you are, respectively" is a pretty good stab at it.  "Laid back" is an idiom that means someone is **unconcerned** and **unanxious**, characterized by a notable *lack* of urgency or worry; as such it can imply **lazy** and **irresponsible**.  "Forward looking" isn't so established as an idiom, but means **concerned** or maybe **ambitious**, characterized by interest in the future and how it might be shaped.